# keyword search over several fields in django

Tags: django

I am using the standard User model of django.

I would like to search users by first name and last name. So I have a free text search and using icontains I am searching for the that text.

However, I would like that a user can search for "John A" and retrieve all users which their First name + Last name contains "John A" however, because I am using icontains over first name and last name separately , it doesn't work. "John" alone will work. but as long as I have involved both fields, it doesn't (which make sense)

Any simple solution for this ?

Comment: So. are you thinking of splittling `John A` as `first_name = 'John'` and `last_name='A'` ?

Comment: Yes. that's how User model implemented. the first_name and lat_name is splitted. you suggest that I'll split the spaces at the back-end ? I was planning more of a search over both fields. Such as a merging the first name and last time when searching. but you suggest the opposite , which can work :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Q objects to create your queries, and use `|` for OR and `&` for AND.

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> qs = Q(first_name__icontains='John A') | Q(last_name__icontains='John A')
>>> User.objects.filter(qs)
```

read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

**p.s.** You can also use `|` and `&` to join regular querysets

```
User.objects.filter(...) | User.objects.filter(...)
```

but I think using Q objects is just neater when going over multiple fields

**edit**

as par your comment, all you want to do is this:

```
>>> query = 'John A'
>>> fn, ln = query.split()
>>> User.objects.filter(first_name=fn, last_name=ln)
```

For complex situations you probably want check the first name and last name. The second one usually is a middle name or part of the others, so icontain will catch it. So something like this:

```
>>> query = 'Jon Van Mendrik'
>>> fn, ln = [i[0], i[-1] for i in query.split()] #take the first and last
>>> print fn, ln
"Jon Mendrik"
>>> qs = Q(first_name__icontains=fn, last_name__icontains=ln)
>>> qs = qs | Q(first_name__icontains=ln, last_name__icontains=fn)
>>> User.objects.filter(qs).distinct()
```

It's not very pretty, but will probably work for most cases, including where the last name was entered first and so on. Just make sure you understand what I did here and not just copy it blindly to your project -

- I took the first and last parts of the string and assigned them to fn and ln respectively
- I create a queryset for the firtcase
- I then joined it to another queryset for the reverse option using `|`
- lastly, I filtered on that queryset and used distinct to get rid of possible duplicates

You can probably add a lot more logic. For example, 'John A' - the last name is obviously an acronym and not the entire name while the first is a full name. You can implement some logic that takes care of that and build the queryset accordingly (`contains` is more costly then `startswith` or then simple comparison). Using Q objects will make that easy. Play around with it, you'll get the hang of it

Comment: That wont work... none of first_name and last_name contains "John A"... first_name contains "John" and last_name contains "A" that's my problem...

Comment: Just got that suggestion from one of the comments. I am worried about a name like "Jon Van Mendrik" :) Or if someone writes "John A" or "A John"

Comment: You'll have to find some logic for that. I'll edit a solution, but there's no clear cut way of doing that

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you use [natural_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/). In your User model, add something like:

```
def natural_key(self):
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

result:

```
users = User.objects.filter()
for user in users:
    print(user.natural_key)
```

You can then filter on natural keys.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I filter by natural key ? User.objects.filters(natural_key__icontains==keywords) ? I dont think that will work...

Comment: I'm down voting because natural keys would be method on the user model which would not exists in the the database to filter over so it clearly does not answer the question and would not work.